# How to get the path of the jar file instead of the path of the running class?

Tags: java, jar, path

I need to know the location of my jar file , so I tried

```
String path = MigrationsApplication.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
```

And this returned

```
file:/C:/Users/fabio/OneDrive/Ambiente de Trabalho/MigrationTool/colbi-migration-tool/target/migrations-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/
```

Although I think I am capable of getting the location of my jar by doing a split by `!` is there a better solution for this?
The final directory that I want in this specific case is target , so can after the split can I use the method getParent?

Comment: The fact that there is a jar file (and in fact a filesystem at all) is an implementation detail. Java can run in environments where there is no filesystem so the "path of the jar" would not be meaningful.  Any solution will have to be (relatively) non-portable.

Comment: @JimGarrison so how can I do it?